# C++ Random Graph Generator Library

Tags: c++, random, graph

I wanted to ask if you know a reliable library to generate random graphs in C++. I have some restrictions like a maximum number of nodes and a maximum connections per node.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting bit of programming, and not too tricky.

Comment: Yeah but I need to test a method so it is better to present the results based on something already well established and accepted by the community.

Comment: use a [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) to represent it and fill the rows randomly

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I need something standard not touched by me so the test can be reliable.

Comment: It is unlikely that you'll find a ready-made library for something so simple that supports *exactly these restrictions*.

Answer (score 3):

Construct a random set of edges (node-node pairings). You can apply restrictions by, e.g., removing a node from the set of available nodes when it reaches its quota of connections.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I need something standard not touched by me so the test can be reliable

Comment: @Altober: I'm not sure anyone would bother to write a library for something this straighforward.

Comment: @Altober: Actually, let me rephrase. I suspect that this problem has too many variables (such as your restrictions) to make it worth implementing a general purpose library.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar interest of generating some random graphs. I found this Boost graph toolkit that can generate an Erdos-Renyi graph, which might answer part of your question, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/doc/erdos_renyi_generator.html.  I haven't tried it out yet.